# MS access Treeview Control slow to load, do I need to use ADO instead of DAO?

Tags: ms-access, vba, treeview, ms-access-2010

I have an activeX treeview control that has 4 levels of nodes (child nodes), each relating to a separate table which is stored on the backend of the database (in-house server). There are 3 queries and 4 dlookups which were required to make this treeview work.

As the database has started to become highly populated, the form with the treeview control has become slow to load (10 seconds). I would like to speed up this load time, I think converting to ADO is something I need to at least consider.

This is the only form that really loads such high quantity of data as its 4 tables and I am thinking that I may need to convert the query recordsets to ADO?

I don't know much about ADO or where its best applied, but as I'm using an activeX control maybe its best suited? I have only used `DAO.recordset` on this form because the various reference VBA available use it.

- Is ADO more appropriate for this scenario?
- Will using ADO speed up the load time of my form?
- Is it complicated to convert recordsets used in VBA to ADO?

NB: I'm not entirely sure how to go about converting my VBA code to ADO recordsets, but if its not appropriate I wont bother learning it

Comment: How much data are we talking about? Have you confirmed the delay is due to rendering as opposed to query time?  The nice thing about a treeview is that you can choose to only load data on demand when a node is expanded.

Comment: Level 1: 24 records.... L2: 10.... L3: 260..... L4:900. And the bottom level will get considerably larger in time. How do I the "only load when clicked" or see if it is already applied?

Comment: Converting to ADO won't get you noteworthy performance benefits (maybe even the opposite). The Treeview control being an ActiveX object has nothing to do with how you load your records.

Comment: @Andre Thank you, I will look in to alternative solutions if that is the case.

Comment: I suggest a new question where you present the code to load the treeview with some sample data, so we can have a look. Or search for something like "vba treeview load on demand"

Comment: @Andre I will research and attempt first and see how far I get on my own.

Comment: I totally agree with @Andre ADO or DAO is not the problem.
Try to use internal table first, and look the time is needed to load your tree. When you load your tree you can load all nodes in level 1 to 3 and then in the node_click() event add or refresh the Level4 child nodes  with the same code you use now when you load your Level4 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

the "trick" for fast loading a treeview is twofold

a) You should save / calculate the "Level-Number" (0 = Ground level,
    1 etc. ) in beforehand so that you have the level-number handy when
    loading so that you can load the whole tree in one step without
    recursive searching. I personally always have a separate local
    treeview-table which contains all things, especially the
    level-number

b) Load the table info before loading into an Array and load it from
    there.  best regards Klaus