# Load on demand for an Active x treeview control that is slow to load (MS access)

Tags: ms-access, vba, treeview

I recently asked [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336640/ms-access-treeview-control-slow-to-load-do-i-need-to-use-ado-instead-of-dao), based on an active x treeview control which is slow to load. The comments from the previous question advise me to add a "load on demand".

The treeview control has 4 levels of nodes and through testing I have found that only the 4th level is the problem.

I cannot work out how to properly code this "load on demand". What I would like to happen is, first three levels load on open and then when the user clicks on a third level the fourth level loads for that appropriate node.

Is this the correct approach I should take in order to speed up the load time?

I think that I need to add a `node_click()` event in order to load the fourth level. How do I add a node click event for only the third level which adds a child node?

here's my third level:

```
strSQL1 = "Select * From Prt_Section ORDER BY Section_Number"
Set myRSChild1 = MyDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL1, dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not myRSChild1.EOF
   Set nodx = Treeview1.Nodes.Add("A" & CStr(myRSChild1![PartCatID]), tvwChild, "B" & CStr(myRSChild1![SectionID]), _
              " " & Format$(myRSChild1![Section_Number], "00") & " - " & _
              myRSChild1![Section_Description])
   myRSChild1.MoveNext
 Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct approach I should take in order to speed up the load time?

You will be spending less time populating the TreeView and presumably using a query that returns fewer rows or is less complex, so probably.

---

To do this you need to identify the initially unpopulated Node - simplest way is to give it a fixed `.Key` or `.Tag` - then when a node is clicked with a matching value, if it has not already been populated, populate it:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeClick(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    If Node.Key = "FOO" And Node.Children = 0 Then

        '//get data
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add Node.Key, tvwChild, , Rnd
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add Node.Key, tvwChild, , Rnd
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add Node.Key, tvwChild, , Rnd
    End If
End Sub
```